# Problemas con importar fichero csv a mi base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema y es que mi codigo `php` no importa los datos de mi fichero `csv` me gustaria a ver si podeis darme alguna idea de como cambiar mi codigo para que pueda funcionar.

Mi codigo `php` es el siguiente:

```
<?php

class csv extends mysqli {

    private $state_csv = false;
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct("localhost","","","");

        if ($this->connect_error) {
            echo "File to connect Database: ". $this ->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function import($file=''){
        $file = fopen($file, 'r');

        while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {

            $value = "'". implode("'/'", $row) ."'";
            $q = "INSERT INTO actividadImport(id,name,surname) VALUES(". $value .");";
            if ($this->query($q)) {
                $this->state_csv = true;
            } else {
                $this->state_csv = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Mi fichero `csv` esta estructurado de la siguiente forma:

```
1/Oriol/Molina
2/Ricardo/Martinez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trate de adaptarlo a tu sentencia de SQL, pero básicamente esto es lo que yo hago cuando importo datos desde un CSV.

Solo me he enfocado en la parte donde se hace el proceso de importación.
Espero te ayude un poco.

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "/")) !== FALSE){
       $q = "INSERT INTO actividadImport(id,name,surname) VALUES ($data[0],$data[1],$data[2])";
       }
       fclose($handle);
```

Comment: No me ha funcionado pero creo que el problema es mio, si puedes pon tu codigo php completo para ver como haces el import desde el principio. Gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Aquí la explicación del código es que con el while iras recorriendo el archivo csv linea por linea, en cada linea vas a recoger los campos en modo de array donde por ejemplo el "id" seria el que esta en la posición [0] el "name" seria la posición [1] y el "surname" el [2]. solo tendrías tal vez que hacer un ajuste en la sentencia sql, tal vez le falte alguna comilla, yo lo he puesto solo de manera ilustrativa. pero la lógica esta correcta. No te pongo todo el código porque yo uso varias funciones para validar el tipo de datos que meto en la instrucción sql. Es muy largo e irrelevante.

Comment: Ya me funciona correctamente era problema de la linea sql que habia que canviar '".$data[0]."'. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Por nada amigo, es bueno ayudar a los demas. Saludos